# Fields inside a ReferenceManyInput have empty values

Tags: react-admin

I am trying `<ReferenceManyInput>` with a setup similar to the [docs example](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceManyInput.html). My inputs are rendered, but all of them have empty values, although related records themselves are fetched correctly. What could be wrong?

My edit component:

```jsx
const CourseEdit = () => {
    return (
        <Edit mutationMode="optimistic">
            <SimpleForm>
                ...
                <ReferenceManyInput reference="prices" target="course">
                    <SimpleFormIterator inline>
                        <TextInput name="label" source="label" />
                        <NumberInput name="value" source="value" />
                        <BooleanInput name="defaultPrice" source="defaultPrice" />
                    </SimpleFormIterator>
                </ReferenceManyInput>
                ...
            </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    );
}
```

This is the API response for this page:

```json
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Course",
  "@id": "/api/courses/59",
  "@type": "Course",
  "created": "2023-08-11T04:59:07+02:00",
  "updated": "2023-09-24T20:26:57+02:00",
  "mentor": {
    "@id": "/api/mentors/55",
    "@type": "Mentor",
    ...
  },
  "dateStart": "2024-06-17T00:00:00+02:00",
  "dateEnd": "2024-06-20T00:00:00+02:00",
  "venue": {
    "@id": "/api/venues/34",
    "@type": "Venue",
    ...
  },
  "published": false,
  "availability": "available",
  "prices": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/prices/115",
      "@type": "Price",
      "created": "2023-09-16T21:08:57+02:00",
      "updated": "2023-09-24T20:26:57+02:00",
      "label": "3 lessons",
      "value": 49900,
      "defaultPrice": true
    },
    {
      "@id": "/api/prices/116",
      "@type": "Price",
      "created": "2023-07-12T20:07:39+02:00",
      "updated": "2023-09-24T20:26:57+02:00",
      "label": "4 lessons",
      "value": 64900,
      "defaultPrice": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't really have a knowledge how (or what) I should debug in a React app, but I can see, that a context provider that wraps the `<SimpleFormIterator>` has all the correct values, while the inputs further down the tree do not:

[context provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgDWB.png)

[field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpSjt.png)

I was expecting to be able to edit related record in the editing screen of the parent record, as described in [the docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceManyInput.html). Actual result is – all the input fields of related records are displayed with empty values.

Comment: `<ReferenceManyInput>` is a component included in the [Enterprise Edition](https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise) of React Admin, which gives you access to a dedicated [support desk](https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise#support) upon subscription. You can probably ask for help there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing `name` attribute from the input components inside the iterator. React Admin uses `name` internally, so by having it in my code I was breaking the RA's internal handling of it.